# Cordova Plugin requires config.xml entries but I use Capacitor

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, ionic4, capacitor

I have to use [cordova-plugin-deeplinks](https://github.com/e-imaxina/cordova-plugin-deeplinks) **because another library is using it**. (I know that Capacitor provides `Plugins.App.addListener('appUrlOpen'...)`).

If I would run a Cordova project, I would need a config.xml looking like this:

```
<universal-links>
 <host name="example.com" event="keycloak" />
</universal-links>
```

Can I use the `capacitor.config.json` file somehow?

Comment: You can set cordova preferences in capacitor.config.json, but in this case, for this plugin you mention, looks like it uses those entries to configure the native project, so, what you need to do is to configure the native project yourself.

Comment: yeah, I did Apple's universal link stuff in the native project and it's opening the app, when clicking a link. But the Keycloak JS library listens for the `event="keycloak"`. This event naming is a feature coming from the cordova plugin. Can you tell me how I can convert the xml format into a valid `capacitor.config.json` format? Or is this not possible?